# ECW support in QGIS3 for Mac

Tags: qgis, mac, ecw

I reinstalled QGIS3 on a new mac but cannot get ECW support to work anymore.

I previously used QGIS3 on another Mac, where I installed ECW support using the "old" method ([see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124794/installing-qgis-with-ecw-support-on-mac)).

This method is not described in the new installer by William Kyngesburye.

How do we get ECW to be supported now?